# Cucumber and WebServices

Tags: web-services, cucumber

Sorry if this has already been answered, but I looking to automate webservice responses and struggling to find correct gem for it? Can any tell me or share a link which shows webservice automation with Cucumber?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - are you looking to write Cucumber features which test a web service, rather than a website?  e.g. making API calls and verifying responses, etc.?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Making calls and verifying responses.

Comment: The Cucumber Book, currently in beta, has a chapter on this. http://pragprog.com/book/hwcuc/the-cucumber-book